# How to configure Load Balancing Servers

Tags: linux, centos7, litespeed

I want to configure load balancing servers on Cloudflare. They have a feature where I can add a couple of servers to improve uptime and service availability.

Now, I'm still a novice in this server stuff. All I want to know is do I need duplicate servers for load balancing?

If yes, my first server is hooked up to my website's domain. Will I be required to add the same domain on the second server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (depending on what you mean by add the same domain)

Cloudflare offers DNS load balancing which means DNS response to queries for your domain name will balance across two IP addresses (there are smart things like directing people to the most local server etc too)
In your case the two servers would be required to be acting on behalf of the same domain name.